# pandas pivot aggregate percentage by index value counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-02', '2013-04-02'],
               'month': ['1','1','3','3','5'],
              'pmonth': ['1', '1', '2', '5', '5'],
              'duration': [30, 15, 20, 15, 30],
             'user_id': ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']})
```

I can calculate the percent of userid count by date,month and pmonth using

```
pd.crosstab(index=[df.date,df.month,df.pmonth],columns=df.duration,values=df.user_id,normalize ='index',aggfunc='count')
```

But i want to calculate the percent of userid in  date,month combination only, is it possible using crosstab.

Comment: can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide the expected output of the analysis. It's not clear what your objective is.